# Adding ecommerce options to existing site using PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7, webshop

What I intend to do is to keep my website with the CMS that I have in place for 12 years because last year I've redesigned it and I've even implemented a very nice AMP version.

To my existing site which includes also product pages, I would like to integrate an ecommerce solution and the one that I like the most is Presta Shop.

Rather than migrating the content to Presta Shop, I want to just bring the stock, price, quantity and add to cart to the existing site via php by calling Presta Shop and fetching specific product IDs.

Is this possible?

So far I didn't find anything about how could this be achieved.

I've read that it could be done in Magento, but nothing for Presta Shop.

Grateful if you have any insights on this.

Many thanks,
Mihai Bocsaru

Answer (score 1):

You have few options, you can use PrestaShop API via Webservice, you can also create your store in some subdirectory and copy layout from your current website

Third option would be to have PrestaShop installation on the same server and just get all the information data from its database, of course entire checkout process should be handled via PrestaShop, this is why most common scenario is to just use website layout with proper e-commerce addition, downside of those two options is that you'll have two administration panels but i guess it's not that big issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Krystian!

I've presented the client the benefits of having the Presta Shop run on its own folder or sub-domain, but he wants it within the site.

We might have to integrate Presta Shop ecommerce options that I've mentioned on this topic within the current web pages and adjust the look and feel of the checkout pages to match the site layout (registration, login, checkout etc.).

I will consider involving you in settings this up.